# Running out of threads in threadpool

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have an application that acts as an intermideate. It takes data from multiple machines and fowards to client machine through sockets. Every time the data is received new thread is created and data is sent to client.At one point available threads in pool becomes zero and application stops working.I even tried using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

This is the function where new thread is created.

```
public void SendFeed(string data, string Key)
{
    Datadelegate _ProcessData = new Datadelegate(ProcessData);
    Form1.countEQ = Form1.countEQ + 1;
    TCPListenerForm.DataClass sObj = new TCPListenerForm.DataClass();
    sObj.DataByte = data;
    sObj.Key = Key;
    try
    {
        _ProcessData.BeginInvoke(sObj, completedCallback, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a bug where your threads aren't terminating. Or you are creating far, far too many of them...

Comment: i have also tried with threadpool, it manages thread termination.In my application second case is happening ,at a time large amount of data is recived in this case application hangs and eventually stops working. I need a solution where i can handle large amount of data.

Comment: Are your threads actually finishing? I haven't ever encountered this with highly threaded applications...